# div and form in the same line

Tags: html, css

it is in the same line but the form has diffrent height...
any idea?

**Code:**

```
<div id="link-social">
<form class="search" method="post" action="">
    <input id="search-box" type="text">
</form>
<a href="http://instagram.com/" class="instagram"></a>
<a href="http://facebook.com/" class="facebook"></a>
</div>

#link-social {
   background:url(img/wbg.png) repeat;
   width:388px;
   height:56px;
   float:left;
   text-align:left;
   display: inline-block;
}

.search {
    display: inline;
}

.facebook {
background-image: url('img/facebook.png');
width:29px;
height:29px;
display: inline-block;
}

.instagram {
background-image: url('img/instagram.png');
width:29px;
height:29px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: A `form` has margins by default, is that what you are seeing?

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in your code that would suggest they should be the same height? (I assume you think they should be, or is this just something you are trying to achieve?) You are setting the height of the containing `div`, but allowing the `form` to _flow_?

Answer (score 2):

Make Your form  `display: block;`
because  `display: inline;` its height and width are depending on its content 
Here is the solution
[Here is the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/yMK6U/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#link-social *{display: inline-block;}` or simply you should change the inline with inline-block in your `.search`.

The good thing you could display all of your element as `table-cell` and align it middle.

Answer (score 0):

Use reset class for CSS

In this case, use

```
form {  
margin:0;  
padding:0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the icons in the different div tags and use float property on the divs or any column framework like twitter bootstrap or pure (http://purecss.io/)!

Check that fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z8ENB/

```
<div id="field">
<form class="search" method="post" action="">
    <input id="search-box" type="text">
</form>
</div>
<div id="link-social">
<a href="http://instagram.com/" class="instagram"></a>
<a href="http://facebook.com/" class="facebook"></a>
</div>

div {
    margin-right: 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MNAKE THIS

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMqrd/1/)**

```
.search {
   float:left;
    line-height:29px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css:

```
.search {
    top: -10px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
}
```